# Strange issue with bones moving vertices even though they are not associated with them

Tags: vertex-weights

[image: Strange vertex weight issue or bug?]

I wonder if anyone can help me? I have this strange issue where a vertex (highlighted in the picture in white) has a weight of 1 linked only the neck bone. However, if I move the head bone, the vertex moves with it. Is there anything I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try subdividing neck or head bone and try moving one of them if it works.

Comment: Could you link a file?

Comment: Hi Nathan and Aman, thanks so much for your replies. I ended up just deleting the head and neck bones and replacing them with new ones and it seems to have fixed the problem. Maybe it was a bug in those specific bones? I have overwritten the files now so can't show you them unfortunately!